# formating csv using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

receiving columns in single column like this:
abc| xyz| pqr| qqq

and there related values in row in single cell.

I want to format it like using pandas

abc xyz pqr qqq

and there related values under them

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: sounds like you need to specify your delimiter, do `pd.read_csv(your_file,sep='|')`

Answer (score 0):

As Datanovice already mentioned, it looks like you need to specify the delimiter.

I added *index_col* and *names* to make the df even cleaner (guessed on your example).

- index_col tells pandas that the first column in the csv is not the index and that it needs to create one
- names gives you the posibility to define the column header (if they are missing in the csv).

`df = pd.read_csv(your_file, sep="|", index_col=False, names=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD'])`